Cannot find AIC/BIC of my topic modelling after using "lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler" in LDA package
I have used "lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler" to do my topic modelling and LDA visualisation, and now I want to determine which number of models (K) best fits my model. Then I tried to use AIC/BIC but the error occurred that "no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of "list".
I have classed my LDA, which is a list and I know it needs to be a model to run AIC/BIC
How can I fix it?
my r code is:
comments = as.list(tokens1) #tokens1 is the cleaned data
doc.list = strsplit(as.character(comments),split=" ")

term.table = table(unlist(doc.list))
term.table = sort(term.table, decreasing = TRUE)

del = term.table < 5 | nchar(names(term.table))<2
term.table = term.table[!del]
vocab = names(term.table)
get.terms = function(x) {
  index = match(x, vocab)  
  index = index[!is.na(index)]  
  rbind(as.integer(index - 1), as.integer(rep(1, length(index))))   
}
documents = lapply(doc.list, get.terms)
K = 4 
G = 500
alpha = 0.001
eta = 0.03
set.seed(123)

LDA = lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(documents = documents, K = K, 
vocab = vocab, num.iterations = G, alpha = alpha, 
eta = eta, initial = NULL, burnin = 0, compute.log.likelihood = TRUE)

BIC(LDA)
error UseMethod("logLik):
"no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of "list".

Please provide your R code, and data, preferably using dput().

@Edward hi Edward I have edited. Do you know why I cannot run AIC/BIC for LDA?
